# How to permanently configure bluetooth hci device to run in piscan mode

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I am trying to scan classic bluetooth devices using `hcitool scan`.
hciconfig of my device is

`hci0:  Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 9C:B6:D0:3B:22:A8  ACL MTU: 1024:8  SCO MTU: 50:8
    UP RUNNING 
    RX bytes:762 acl:0 sco:0 events:57 errors:0
    TX bytes:3178 acl:0 sco:0 commands:57 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x8f 0xfe 0xd8 0x3f 0x5b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'My_device#1'
    Class: 0x0c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Revision: 0x0
    LMP Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Subversion: 0x25a
    Manufacturer: Qualcomm (29)`

I have observed that when I set `hciconfig hci0 piscan` the `hcitool scan` returns me devices but not otherwise.
How can i set the hci device permanently to piscan mode?

Also is there any reliable way to scan classic bluetooth apart from using hcitool for linux platform?